# How to lock "last modified" date?

Tags: linux, debian, last-modified, ext4

I have a directory on an ext4 filesystem full of files that I may want to modify, for trivial adjustments such as the wrong database name in PHP files. However I wish to preserve the last-modified date. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: You mean the file's mtime? Renaming only affects the atime, because you're changing inode data, not the file's actual content.

Comment: But if I were changing the database name, I would be modifying the actual content of the file...

Comment: then yes, you're modifying the file's contents. so yes, the mtime will change. any reason you need it to stay constant?

Comment: I want to know when the files were last "properly" modified, i.e. significantly modified (when they were developed)

Comment: then you should be using source control, and keep such "trivial" change information in the change logs. e.g. make it a v0.0.1 modification, instead of 0.1 or 1.0

Comment: I need to research that now

Answer (score 1):

You can't "freeze" them, but you can record them, and then re-apply them using **touch**.

That said: using a version control system as suggested by Marc is definitely the way to go.